# Why does my python function treat a string argument as list/array when using Pool apply_async?

Tags: python, pool, apply-async

I'm encountering some strange behavior in my python program. I'm using a `Pool` to run some functions in parallel and using the `apply_async` function. The strange behavior is that, apparently, significantly more arguments are being passed to the function than should be passed.  It's likely something silly, but here is the relevant context:

```py
def do_joesecurity_analysis(filename: str):
    # Stuff
    ...
    return;

...
def do_analysis(args):
    ...
    pool = Pool();

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            ...
            print( type(f) );
            start_analysis = pool.apply_async(do_joesecurity_analysis, args = (f) );
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: do_joesecurity_analysis() takes 1 positional argument but 64 were given
```

Now, the length of the filename happens to be 64 characters long (it's a combination of letters and numbers), and that debugging `print` statement says `<class 'str'>`, so I'm confused as to why it seems to treat each character as an argument.

**Note:** Just to make sure that I wasn't going crazy, I made a normal function call to `do_joesecurity_analysis(f)` (i.e. not in a `Pool`), and the function ran perfectly.

If it's relevant, the interpreter I'm using is version 3.9.1.

If necessary, I will provide additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: `args = (f)` doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I guess you're right. Thanks!